# Cómo centrar elemento <p>

Tags: html, css

por favor, como centro horizontalmente el P
Me toma como centro el borde superior izquierdo. pero no el p completo.
Se que es pregunta muy basica, pero no me acuerdo. gracias

```css
section {
    position: relative;
    background: url(/imagenes/saludoavion.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    max-width: 100vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
    padding-top: 100vh;}
    p {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    color: blue;
    background: chartreuse;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: justify;
    bottom: 50%;}
```

```html
<title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
      <h1>PARALLAX EFFECT</h1>
    </header>
    <section>
      <p>PURO CSS - SIN JAVASCRIPT
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit auam mollitia nobis iure eveniet quaerat laudantium libero, animi est.
      </p>
      </section>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como es posición absoluta hay que especificar: 0 izquierda, 0 derecha y que el margen horizontal sea automático:

```css
p {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    color: blue;
    background: chartreuse;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: justify;
    bottom: 50%; 
    /*centrando el p */
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
    <title>Document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <header>
          <h1>PARALLAX EFFECT</h1>
        </header>
        <section>
          <p>PURO CSS - SIN JAVASCRIPT
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit auam mollitia nobis iure eveniet quaerat laudantium libero, animi est.
          </p>
          </section>
          </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Si solo es centrar horizontalmente, puedes hacerlo sin posición absoluta. Con ponerle un width y el margin lateral auto, ya se centra.

Answer (score 0):

Para centrar el párrafo dentro del contendor bastaría con, primero quitar la **posición absolute** que le has dado y que no te aporta nada según el código que compartes, poniéndola en relative controlaras mejor su posición, luego podrás utilizar la propiedad de CSS "**margin**". En este caso incluyendo un "**margin: 0 auto**", lo que vas a conseguir es que el "p" ocupe el espacio central, dejando 0 pixeles de distancia con el contenido superior e inferior que, por supuesto podrás modificar a tu antojo. El auto en este caso le dará la posición central, dejando el mismo margen a derecha e izquierda con respecto al contenedor del párrafo.

Otro modo de hacerlo sería dándole una posición **left** acorde a la posición que deseas que ocupe en la pantalla. Comparto tu código con el ajuste comentado para que veas el resultado por si fuera lo que estás buscando:

```css
section { 
   position: relative; background: 
   url(/imagenes/saludoavion.jpg); 
   background-size: cover; max-width: 100vw; 
   max-height: 100vh; 
   padding-top: 100vh;} 
p { 
   display: block; 
   position: relative; 
   color: blue; background: 
   chartreuse; 
   width: 300px; 
   height: auto; 
   text-align: justify; 
   bottom: 50%; 
   margin:0 auto;}
```

```html
 <body> 
     <header> 
         <h1>PARALLAX EFFECT</h1> 
     </header> 
    <section> 
      <p>PURO CSS - SIN JAVASCRIPT Lorem ipsum dolor sit auam mollitia nobis iure eveniet quaerat laudantium libero, animi est. </p> 
    </section> 
 </body>
```

A continuación comparto un url de documentación en la que puedes ver con más detalle el uso de estas propiedades [CSS][1]

```
  [1]: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta colocar las etiquetas center en tu código Antes de lo Que Quieras Centrar

O utilizar tranform: translate(0%, 50%); en tu código CSS

```css
section {
    position: relative;
    background: url(/imagenes/saludoavion.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    transform: translate(0%,50%);
    max-width: 100vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
    padding-top: 100vh;}
    p {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    color: blue;
    background: chartreuse;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: justify;
    bottom: 50%;}
```

```html
<title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
      <h1>PARALLAX EFFECT</h1>
    </header>
    <center>
    <section>
    <center>
      <p>PURO CSS - SIN JAVASCRIPT
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit auam mollitia nobis iure eveniet quaerat laudantium libero, animi est.
      </p>
      </center>
      </section>
      </center>
      </body>
    </html>
```

```html
<title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
      <h1>PARALLAX EFFECT</h1>
    </header>
    <section>
      <center>
      <p>PURO CSS - SIN JAVASCRIPT
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit auam mollitia nobis iure eveniet quaerat laudantium libero, animi est.
      </p>
      </center>
      </section>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: las ediciones solo en tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Yo usaría `Flexbox`, para hacerlo mas rápido te muestro el código que implemente y te explico dentro de el para que sirven, por otro lado si te interesa aprender mas sobre `Flexbox` te dejo este [Link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
section {
    position: relative;
    background: url(/imagenes/saludoavion.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex; /*Convertimos al menú en flexbox*/
    justify-content: center; /*con esto centramos a todos los items de manera horizonal*/
    align-items: center; /*con esto centramos de manera vertical*/
}
p {
    color: blue;
    background: chartreuse;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: justify;
}
/*al header le di algunos estilos para que quede mejor con el ejemplo que te estoy dando*/
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>PARALLAX EFFECT</h1>
</header>
<section>
  <p>PURO CSS - SIN JAVASCRIPT
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit auam mollitia nobis iure eveniet quaerat laudantium libero, animi est.
  </p>
</section>
```